# if else statement not working on integer values

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
-- content of sys.argv is 2 and 10 which is assigned to the specified variables. 

wthreshold, cthreshold = sys.argv
def Alerting():
    if PatternCount < wthreshold:
        print
        print LRangeA
        print
        print 'PatternMatch=(' + str(PatternCount) + '),' + 'ExactTimeFrame[' + str(BeginSearchDVar) + ',' + str(EndinSearchDVar) + ']=(Yes)'
        print
        sys.exit(0)
    elif PatternCount >= wthreshold and PatternCount < cthreshold:
        print
        print LRangeA
        print
        print 'PatternMatch=(' + str(PatternCount) + '),' + 'ExactTimeFrame[' + str(BeginSearchDVar) + ',' + str(EndinSearchDVar) + ']=(Yes)'
        print
        sys.exit(1)
    elif PatternCount >= cthreshold:
        print
        print LRangeA
        print
        print 'PatternMatch=(' + str(PatternCount) + '),' + 'ExactTimeFrame[' + str(BeginSearchDVar) + ',' + str(EndinSearchDVar) + ']=(Yes)'
        print
        sys.exit(2)
    else:
        print
        print LRangeA
        print
        print 'PatternMatch=(' + str(PatternCount) + '),' + 'ExactTimeFrame[' + str(BeginSearchDVar) + ',' + str(EndinSearchDVar) + ']=(Yes)'
        print
        sys.exit(3)


LRangeA = """this line 1
another line 2
one more line 3
line 4 
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8"""
PatternCount = len(LRangeA.split('\n'))
Alerting()
```

When I run this code, it doesn't seem to be correctly checking the numbers in the if statements.  The code always seems to go into the first if statement even though the value of PatternCount is 8.

Comment: `wthreshold` is not a number. It's a string. Convert it to a number with `int()`

Comment: Switch to Python 3, and you'll get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` instead of weird results.  It's been out for nearly seven years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wthreshold` and `cthreshold` are  strings coming from the command line arguments. If you want to compare them numerically, you need to convert them to numbers:

```
wthreshold, cthreshold = [int(x) for x in sys.argv]
```

Comment: scriptname, feature, logfile, daterange, stringA, stringB, wthreshold, cthreshold, option = sys.argv  (How would this work if the number of parameters change as is shown here?)

Comment: @swenson Just add more variables to the left side of the operation. Alternatively, you could just explicitly extract them from `arg`. E.g.: `someVariable = int(sys.argv[2]`.